# How do I inspect the class type of attributes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I create a method like:

```
def process_by_type *things

  things.each {|thing|
    case thing.type
      when String

      when Array

      when Hash

      end

    end
  }
end
```

I know I can use kind_of?(Array), etc.  But I think this would be cleaner, and I cant' find a method for it on the Class:Object documentation page.

Comment: If you can use kind_of or is_a, it's definitely better to use them.

Comment: Why?  I don't see any dangers.

Comment: Just because there is no point in reinventing the wheel and because those methods have been extensively used and tested.

Comment: It's generally better to check what methods an object supports (duck typing), instead of what its class hierarchy is. This way, a user of your code can use their own custom class and not be forced into a particular inheritance hierarchy. For example, you can check to see if something is Integer-like (respond_to? :to_int), or convertible to Integer (respond_to? :to_i), rather than checking the type (obj.kind_of?(Integer) or Integer===obj).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the form of case statement like what you're doing:

```
case obj
  when expr1
    # do something
  when expr2
    # do something else
end
```

is equivalent to performing a bunch of if expr === obj (triple-equals comparison). When expr is a class type, then the === comparison returns true if obj is a type of *expr* or a subclasses of *expr*.

So, the following should do what you expect:

```
def process_by_type *things

  things.each {|thing|
    case thing
      when String
        puts "#{thing} is a string"
      when Array
        puts "#{thing} is an array"
      when Hash
        puts "#{thing} is a hash"
      else
        puts "#{thing} is something else"
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!  I'd seen something like this and thought there was some mystery to it, but now I get it!!

Answer (score 3):

Try [.class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001012):

```
>> a = "12"
=> "12"
>> a.class
=> String
>> b = 42
=> 42
>> b.class
=> Fixnum
```